# how to get/store mysql function return value in variable using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

how to get/store mysql function return value in variable using php

```
    Delimiter $
    CREATE FUNCTION FP_USER_EXISTS(xemailid VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS int(11)
    BEGIN
    SET @User_exists = 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @found FROM login WHERE emailid = xemailid;
    IF @found > 0 THEN
     SET @User_exists = 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN @User_exists;
    END $$
```

function calling in mysql

```
   @return=FP_USER_EXISTS('testing@test.com') 
   select @return   here it shows return value 0 or 1
```

but in php it is not returing value

```
       $ret=mysqli_query($connection,"select FP_USER_EXISTS('$emailid')");
      if($ret==1)
      {
         echo "User already exits";
      }
       else
      {
        echo 'Inserted successfully';
      }
```

every time it is showing one value based on condition
 Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php returns an object, not a string. Fetch the object, then you can compare it.

Comment: Chris is right. Just var_dump($ret) it will show all the properties of that object.

Comment: var_dump($ret) it is also return one value please check the code where i have to enhance the code. Thanks